# AUCTeX TeX-doc & texdoc

Tags: emacs, auctex

As far as I can tell from the manual, running <kbd>C-c ?</kbd> in AUCTeX ought to run `texdoc %s` on the package name specified. For the vast majority of packages it does, however some just aren't found - <kbd>M-!</kbd> `texdoc memoir` works fine, but <kbd>C-c ?</kbd> `memoir` fails both at detecting the package under point and then at loading the documentation when I type it in manually.

I've been trying to find the variable which controls the invocation of `texdoc`, but can't. <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(executable-find "texdoc")` returns `/usr/bin/texdoc` as expected, but that's as far as I got.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from version 11.89, AUCTeX binds by default <kbd>C-c ?</kbd> to `TeX-documentation-texdoc`, which does exactly what is asked.

For previous versions of AUCTeX, see the original answer below.

---

I find `TeX-doc` (the function bound to <kbd>C-c ?</kbd>) overly complicated: in the case of `memoir` class it never calls `texdoc memoir` because the doc file is named `memman.pdf` instead of `memoir.pdf`.  That should be fixed upstream.

For the time being, you can use this much simpler function which blindly runs `texdoc <symbol-at-point>` without further checks:

```lisp
(defun mg-TeX-doc ()
  "Search documentation with texdoc for symbol at point."
  (interactive)
  (call-process "texdoc" nil 0 nil "--view" (thing-at-point 'symbol)))
```

You can bind it to <kbd>C-c ?</kbd> if you want to replace standard `TeX-doc` with the following code:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn
     (define-key TeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c ?") 'mg-TeX-doc)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that does is exactly; however I'm having trouble figuring out how to bind it to a key, as 'Symbol’s function definition is void' is thrown every time. Apologies, I'm a newcomer to lisp; what definition should I add (presumably in between the two brackets after defun-?))

Comment: thanks, that was perfect. C-x ? is also unbound, so I used that. I'll look up progn later...

Comment: @2e0byo  Since [`eval-after-load`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html#index-eval_002dafter_002dload-896) takes only one argument after the library to be loaded, [`progn`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequencing.html#index-progn-550) can be used to execute more than one function.  Actually, in this case in which there is only one function, `progn` isn't strictly needed , but it could be useful in the future if you'll need to execute other commands.